# mediawiki removing index.php from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki and I want to remove index.php from my URLs. I looked at the docs on the MediaWiki site but they were not clear to me.

They all wanted to use a URL like this `http://domain.com/wiki/page` I want to use `http://domain.com/page`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a read of why [it's probably a bad idea to place the wiki in the root.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_in_site_root_directory)

Answer (score 6):

The documentation is fairly clear on their website. You can have a look [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL#URL_like_-_example.com.2FPage_title) for complete documentation (I direct linked your use case), including examples of various other configurations on different web servers.

Comment: If you're going to downvote 5 years after the fact, explain why or offer an edit.

Answer (score 3):

I felt the documentation too lengthy and not very helpful. The wizard option given in documentation is the easiest way to configure wiki on main domain.

```
http://shorturls.redwerks.org/
```

This website has a wizard to easily configure shortURL for wiki.

As you want Article name as `http://domain.com/page`

1. submit wiki folder at http://shorturls.redwerks.org Eg. example.com/wiki_folder/ or example.com if folder is on root web folder
2. After submission change The Article Path textbox to `/$1` and submit

The script will provide exact configuration code as per your requirements

Comment: This tool is amazing!  For my particular setup, the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` wasn't defined well, so I removed it, and the generated one worked great!  (Also I commented out the second rewrite rule: `# RewriteRule ^/?$ /w/index.php [L]`)

Comment: shorturls.redwerks.org **NOT WORKS**!! The http://shorturls.redwerks.org not works with `example.com` as "root web folder", even `http://example.com/wiki_folder` produces "Sorry, this does not look like a wiki"!

Answer (score 0):

This could be your solution:
`{{#titleparts:{{fullurl:page}}|3|1}}`

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23titleparts
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_data