# Removing index.php from MediaWiki action URLs

Tags: mediawiki

OK so its [fairly well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667847/mediawiki-removing-index-php-from-url) how to hide the index.php?title= bit from urls, but what I would like is to hide it for all the action type links, similar to how the extension [ShortUrls](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aShortLinks) is supposed to work (It doesn't on my site and I don't know how to fix it). I don't have access to .htaccess and was thinking of doing it by adding some javascript to the common.js page, or by modifying the ShortLinks extension but the documentation on those hooks isn't very good and anything I tried wasn't helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to add an entry to [`$wgActionPaths`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgActionPaths) for each action that you want to use a short URL for.

For example, if you want the normal view URL of the page `Foobar` to be `/wiki/Foobar`, and the edit and history URLs to be, say, `/wiki/edit/Foobar` and `/wiki/history/Foobar`, you'd add the following lines to your LocalSettings.php:

```php
$wgArticlePath = '/wiki/$1';
$wgActionPaths['edit'] = '/wiki/edit/$1';
$wgActionPaths['history'] = '/wiki/history/$1';
```

Of course, you'll also need to configure your web server to rewrite any requests for those short URLs back into something MediaWiki will understand, e.g. using mod_rewrite on Apache.  The documentation page I linked to above has some helpful examples.

---

More generally, you can transform MediaWiki-generated URLs in arbitrary ways using a [GetLocalURL](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/GetLocalURL) or [GetLocalURL::Internal](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/GetLocalURL%3a%3aInternal) hook.  (The main difference between the two hooks is that the GetLocalURL hook is also called for interwiki URLs.)  These hooks are called from the [Title::GetLocalURL()](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/edbd8ea6b32d8859ef8e1f77ba6d0e43afaea06e/includes/Title.php#L1637), which you may want to take a look at to see how they work.

For example, here's how you could transform diff URLs into the format `/wiki/diff/revA/revB/Page_name`:

```php
function prettyDiffURLs( $title, &$url, $query ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/^diff=(\w+)&oldid=(\w+)$/', $query, $matches ) ) {
        $dbkey = wfUrlencode( $title->getPrefixedDBkey() );
        $url = "/wiki/diff/$matches[1]/$matches[2]/$dbkey";
    }
    return true;
}
$wgHooks['GetLocalURL::Internal'][] = 'prettyDiffURLs';
```

(Warning: I believe this code should work, but I have not tested it!)

Comment: That is awesome, thank you so much :D is there any similar way to make the diff urls on the RecentChanges feed to the same?

Comment: also would there be any way of adding the section number (and potentially section title) to the end of the edit url? that would be so cool

Comment: @FallingBullets: You can do all that (and more!) by writing a custom hook; see edit above.

Comment: Ok, the wgHook worked but it's missing the 'Compare selected revisions' button and other combinations of diff/oldid/newid/etc queries. Thank you for all your help and I'm sorry for not getting back to you sooner, I didn't notice/get a notification.

Comment: there's such a large number of urls that get pushed to `/w/index.php?`, is there any better way of hooking into it? it would also be cool to redirect namespaces to `/$NS/$title` for example `/category/things`?

Answer (score 0):

My eventual answer (thanks to the above answer) is:

```php
function pretty_diff($title, &$url, $query)
{
        if ( preg_match('/diff=(\w+)&oldid=(\w+)/', $query, $matches))
        {
                $dbkey = wfUrlencode($title->getPrefixedDBkey());
                $url = "/wiki/$dbkey?$matches[0]";
        }
        return true;
}
$wgHooks['GetLocalURL::Internal'][] = 'pretty_diff';
```

but I eventually replaced it with a javascript function to potentially cover more links